# Clicking sound from AC on startup

Tags: jeep, hvac, grand-cherokee

I have a 2008 Jeep Grand Cherokee that makes a very loud clicking noise when I turn the AC on just after starting the car. It only happens every so often and it lasts about 20 seconds. It sounds like it's coming from the passenger side dash. I've done some research and I think it may be the blend door actuator, but I don't change between the AC and heat. I was just wondering if it could still be that even though I'm not switching between heat and AC. Thank you.

Comment: Blend door gear box sounds about right, one of the plastic gears probably broke loose and gets caught up sometimes

Comment: Check out the internal components here https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=T6gQp2wbif4